# Need help using ascii to write .dat files

Tags: python, ascii, astropy

Currently, I'm trying to use `astropy.io.ascii` in python anaconda to write a `.dat` file that includes data I've already read in (using `ascii`) from a different `.dat` file. I defined a specific table in the pre-existing file to be Data, the problem with Data is that I need to multiply the first of the columns by a factor of 101325 to change it's units, and I need fourth of the four columns to disappear entirely. So I defined the first column as `Pressure_pa` and I converted its units, then I defined the other two columns to be `Altitude_km` and `Temperature_K`. Is there any way I can use `ascii`'s `write` function to tell it to write a `.dat` file containing the three columns I defined? And how would I go about it? Below is the code that has brought me up to the point of having defined these three columns of data:

```
from astropy.io import ascii
Data=ascii.read('output_couple_121_100.dat',guess=False,header_start=384,data_start=385,data_end=485,delimiter=' ')
Pressure_pa=Data['P(atm)'][:}*101325
Altitude_km=Data['Alt(km)'][:]
Temperature_K=Data['T'][:]
```

Now I thought that I might be able to use `ascii.write()`, to write a `.dat` file with `Pressure_pa`, `Altitude_km` and `Temperature_K` into the same file, is there any way to do this?

Comment: so where is your code, actual input/output and desired behavior? in current state it is unclear what are you asking for, take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I edited the question to try and clarify it better, sorry I'm rather new to this community I just started working with python this semester of college, I'm using it to do astrophysical research. Anyways, I included the code that has brought me up to the point I'm at, I've attempted a couple of different ways at writing the file, if I type ascii.write(Pressure_pa,sys.stdout) it will output just the data in that column, which is the same for the other two columns. I tried writing them all together, but I get an error message: unhashable text: Column

Comment: It's *really* important to tag a question like this one appropriately. Without a reference to `astropy`, none of the rest makes any sense. `astropy.io.ascii` is something very different than the ASCII codec in general.

Comment: @Blckknght I'll keep that in mind for tagging in the future, any ideas on writing .dat files with astropy.io.ascii?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know anything about `astropy` at all. Have you checked the docs for `astropy.io.ascii`? What sort of arguments does it expect?

Comment: @Blckknght I read a couple more articles and I found the answer! I'll try to post it in case anyone else has a similar problem, the only thing I still can't figure out is how to multiply the first column by a factor of 101325

Answer (score 2):

So I think I figured it out! I'll create a more generic version to fit others

```
    from astropy.io import ascii
    Data=ascii.read('filename.dat',guess=False,header_start=1,data_start=2,data_end=10,delimiter=' ')
    #above: defining Data as a certain section of a .dat file beginning at line 2 through 10 with headers in line 1
    ascii.write(Data,'new_desired_file_name.dat',names=['col1','col2','col3','col4'],exclude_names=['col3'],delimiter=' ')
    #above: telling ascii to take Data and creat a .dat file with it, when defining the names, define a name for every column in Data and then use the exclude_names command to tell it not to include those specific columns
```